# When should I load the state specific data in AngularJS, on loading of application or when user navigates to the particular state?

Tags: angularjs, architecture, single-page-application

I am developing an SPA using AngularJS. I have a Home state which is the default state and loads as first state when application loads. On Home state I have provided the links to other states. In all other states some data is common which is to be bound to drop-down lists in those states e.g. All states has Region drop-down and country drop-down and data to bind to these drop-down would always be the same. Each state also has one more drop-down list for user preference and data bound to this drop-down list is different for each state. I am getting all the data from Database.

As region and country data is common for all the states hence on the load of Home state, this data is loaded from database and saved in cache and then it is used in any other state from cache only and we save Server and Database hit.

But I am confused for User-Preference data, as it is state specific so should I also load all of it while Home state is loading and cache it or should I load it only when user navigates to some other state and then just load the User-preference data for that state only and cache it?.

I am more inclined in the direction of "as and when required loading of data" from Database. But some others in my team are of opinion that as this data is not much and would even take less than 5 seconds to get all the user preferences for all the states from database then we should load all while loading the home state and cache it (i.e. on application load itself).

Please suggest what should be better approach and will be happy if you provide your reasoning too for favouring the one over other.

Comment: User-preference data is less today but in future it will increase. Also the strategy we decide now will be used later on in SPA for other such functionalities.

Comment: 1. you shouldn't assume users will always start with the home state. They should be able to go on a specific state, and refresh or bookmark it for later. 2. 5 seconds is quite a long time. I would hate having to wait 5 seconds before seeing a page. Use a service to load the data, load it when needed (for everything), and cache it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet for the reply. So loading of data as and when required is a good strategy. 5 seconds is bit higher, I tested it again and found that total time taken if we load everything on home state and cache it then it is close 2.5 seconds.